# Teaching Jewish morals/ethics to children: books and other aids

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, children-parenting, morality

Looking for books with ethical and moral dilemnas (scenarios) that can serve as starting points for discussions with kids 7 year old and older to explore Jewish moral and ethical values and laws.  Not looking for stories that say that if you are observant everything will turn out fine.

I am looking for things like the "Shabbat Table Discussions" put out by YU:
http://www.yutorah.org/shabbattable/

Scenarios with teaching points linked to Jewish sources preferred.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with Judaism at all.

Comment: @DoubleAA  Asked on  forum titled "Judaism" I thought the relevance to Judaism was obvious.  It seems not.  I have edited the question to explicate what I thought was obvious.

Comment: This still appears too broad.

Comment: @msh i still think this is off topic. what is uniquely jewish being sought? a book of moral quandaries isn't Jewish. this is like asking for a book of math lessons so someone can calculate shiurim of a mikvah.

Comment: @DoubleAA  Just as there secular ways to view work on the holidays, morals and ethics, there are Jewish ways to view these topics.  I do not know what you do not understand.

Comment: There certainly are Jewish ethical values. I don't know why you think I doubted that or why that matters.

Comment: Yehuda, to clarify @DoubleAA's point if I understand it correctly, it that it looks like you are looking for _scenarios_ that serve as a platform for moral discussions. Those discussion may be from a Jewish perspective, or not, but the scenarios would be the same.

Comment: The Thinking Jewish Teenager's Guide to Life. A very sophisticated book, though

Comment: how about Genesis?

Answer (score -1):

Something I've found really useful for this purpose is the [Tanakh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanakh).  I really recommend the [box set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanakh#Books_of_the_Tanakh).  [Its](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.34.30-31?lang=bi) [constituent](http://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.1.16-19?lang=bi) [books](http://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.18.5?lang=bi) [contain](http://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.27.1-4?lang=bi) [a](http://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.20.5-8?lang=bi) [large](http://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.9?lang=bi) [number](http://www.sefaria.org/Judges.11.30-31?lang=bi) [of](http://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.24.5-8?lang=bi) [moral](http://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.19.9-14?lang=bi), [ethical](http://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.39?lang=bi), [and](http://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.38.24-27?lang=bi) [theological](http://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.36.32?lang=bi) [dilemmas](http://www.sefaria.org/Jonah.1.7-16?lang=bi) [that](http://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.60?lang=bi) [lead](http://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.6.1-5?lang=bi) [to](http://www.sefaria.org/Job.1-42?lang=bi) [a](http://www.sefaria.org/Song_of_Songs.2.7?lang=bi) [plethora](http://www.sefaria.org/Ruth.1.8-19?lang=bi) [of](http://www.sefaria.org/Lamentations.5.17-22?lang=bi) [jumping](http://www.sefaria.org/Ecclesiastes.1.2-3?lang=bi) [off](http://www.sefaria.org/Esther.4.13-14?lang=bi) [points](http://www.sefaria.org/Daniel.12.8?lang=bi) [for](http://www.sefaria.org/Ezra.10.1-15?lang=bi) [discussion](http://www.sefaria.org/II_Chronicles.30.13-20?lang=bi).  As a bonus, there is a copious amount of [supplementary reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_commentaries_on_the_Bible) to give you various different approaches to the topics.

Comment: OP wants a book that focuses on the dilemmas specifically.

Comment: @ClintEastwood "Looking for books with ethical and moral dilemnas (scenarios)" I think the Tanakh contains plenty of ethical and moral dilemmas.